# Sass - How to Import a Message into Directive

Tags: sass

I use `@warn` a lot, but I'd like to import pre-written messages into my warnings that are stored for example in another function or file.

Is this possible?

I know the following won't work, but so you get the idea...

```
@if $a == 'red' {
    color: red;
} @else if $a == 'blue' {
    color: blue;
} @else {
    @warn '@include error-msg_no-color-detected';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using variables...

```
$msg: 'Something went wrong!';

@if ... {
    ...
} @else {
    @warn: '#{$msg}';
}
```

This allows me to create a `_debug.scss` file containing lots of messages.

```
@import 'config';
@import 'debug';
@import 'dark';
@import 'application';
```

_debug.scss:

```
@msg-1: 'Oops!';
@msg-2: 'No color defined. Check the config file.';
```